# iPhone 4 restart when the lock button is broken

Tags: iphone, hardware, restart

My iPhone 4 suddenly just crashed and turned itself off - without any Message. I've tried to plug it in to my PC, but I can't get my iPhone to power up. The Apple logo appears for about 3 seconds, and then it disappears - it happens consistently. My lock button is also broken, so I can't reboot it.

How can I power the device up?

Comment: Are you anywhere near an Apple store? This may be a good time to schedule an appointment and then take it in.

Answer (score 2):

Plugging a phone into a computer or power source via the usb cable will power it on, even if it is off – your phone is in need of repair or replacement.

I've seen the apple logo appearing for a few seconds and then phone dying several times with dead phones. I've fixed countless phones, but I don't have a concrete answer for this problem other than it being related to the motherboard in your phone and the solution is a replacement (replacement part more than value of the phone)

Comment: thank you! I finally got it synced With itunes, but I have to do a hard reset... I'm now worry that my dear pics will be gone :-( Any tips about how i'm gonna get them back? Thanks again!

Comment: if you're using a Mac it should load iPhoto when you plug it in and you simply select them. On Windows I think it opens a folder in explorer? I don't really know since I haven't used Windows with an iPhone in about 4 years.. If it's syncing you can get your pics though. Depending on your settings, it may already be backing up your pics. (if you did a back up then you're set, pics, settings and apps)